# Using a Global Array or Lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have an assignment to take the input of a list of characters/integers of a math problem in prefix notation and output the result or an error if the input is wrong.  The input will be main([list], X) and the output should be the result.

My problem is trying to use a stack in a way that I would in C to so I can use the prefix methodology I know but don't know how to implement it.

I currently get an error trying to use OStack([]). as a declaration and was wondering if someone can explain or show the basic setup of using a global list/array or if I have to  to use the passed list from main and create multiple methods.

Specifically I want to know if I can use OpStack and OStack similar to how I have it now, and how I can do that.

Thank you.

```
/* Used to imitate a stack */
pop(E, [E|Es],Es).
push(E, Es, [E|Es]).
seehead([X|TAIL],X).


OpStack([]).
OStack([]).

loop(Y,[X|TAIL]) :- integer(X), !,
                 pop(Popped, OStack, OStack),
             pop(Marker, OpStack, OpStack),
             pop(Operator, OpStack, OpStack),
         Z is Y + Operator + Popped,
         ( integer(seehead([TAIL],Z)) ->
          loop(Y, [Pop2|OStack]);
          push(Z, OStack, OStack), main(TAIL,X)
         ).


main([X |[]], X):-write(X).

main([X| TAIL],Z):- X == +, !, push(+, OpStack, OpStack), push("X", OStack, OStack),           main(TAIL, Z).
main([X| TAIL],Z):- X == *, !, push(*, OpStack, OpStack), push("X", OStack, OStack),     main(TAIL, Z).
main([X| TAIL],Z):- X == -, !, push(-, OpStack, OpStack), push("X", OStack, OStack), main(TAIL, Z).
main([X| TAIL],Z):- X == /, !, push(/, OpStack, OpStack), push("X", OStack, OStack), main(TAIL, Z).

main([X|TAIL], Z):-  integer(X),!,
         ( seehead([TAIL],Z) == "X" ->
          push(X, OStack, OStack), main(TAIL,X);
           loop(Y,OStack)
        ).
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains some syntax problems, that SWI-Prolog kindly highlights.

```
...
seehead([X|TAIL],X).  % use _TAIL. Note that usuall this is named peek
...
OpStack([]).  % first letter MUST be lowercase!
OStack([]).   % ditto
...
pop(Marker, OpStack, OpStack), % Marker is singleton!
...
loop(Y, [Pop2|OStack]);  % Pop2 is singleton!
...
loop(Y,OStack) % Y is singleton!
...
```

Singletons are useless, and usually indicate a typo.

But generally I think you're tackling the problem from the wrong viewpoint. Prolog has an hallmark for declarative programming, usually this means **simpler** code than procedural programming. And the stack is *implicit* in evaluation, Prolog *is* a recursion based language. No need for simulating a stack (to be true, for this example also C would better use recursion than a simulated stack).

Thus, striving for simplicity, implement the spec:

```
main(List, X) :- loop(List, [], X).

loop([+|R], R2, N) :- !,
   loop(R, R1, T1),
   loop(R1, R2, T2),
   N is T1+T2.
...
loop([N|R], R, N) :-
   integer(N), !. % you will need to translate the character to number, I've simplified here

loop(Spec, _, _) :- % catchall rule 
   write(error_here(Spec)), nl,
   fail. % no error recovery, just print
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still trying to get used to Syntax and trying to force something I knew could work from the big picture but was poorly planned was getting me frustrated.

Comment: Prolog is rather different than other languages, and can be frustrating. I would suggest to try to complete my snippet, should be fairly easy. But of course, debugging your code and make it works would be much more useful for your learning experience.